# Vue styling local components

Tags: css, vue.js

I have Single-File Components and I want to use it in different places like subscribe page and footer.
But I want to style to be different.
Is it possible to style local components?

Component file: Newsletter.vue

```
<template>
<form>
    <label>Enter your email address here</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" required/>
</form>
  <button @click="subscribe" >
    SUBSCRIBE
  </button>
</template>
```

Subscribe page: Subscribe.vue

let say style Newsletter background-color green and align to left

```
<template>
 <h2>
  Subscribe to receive Newsletter
  </h2>
  <Newsletter></Newsletter>
</template>

<script>
import Newsletter from "@/components/Newsletter.vue";

export default {
 components: {
  Newsletter
 }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
 Newsletter{
  background-color: green;
  text-align:left;
 }
</style>
```

Subscribe page: Footer.vue

but in Footer, I want to style Newsletter background-color red and align center

```
   <template>
      <h2>
        JOIN OUR NEWSLETTER
      </h2>
      <Newsletter></Newsletter>
   </template>

<script scoped>
import Newsletter from "@/components/Newsletter.vue";

export default {
 components: {
  Newsletter
 }
}
</script>

<style>
 Newsletter{
  background-color: red;
  text-align:center;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options. You may benefit from using the `::v-deep` combinator which allows leaking the style to the child components.

Using your example with a small change:

```
<template>
 <h2>
  Subscribe to receive Newsletter
  </h2>
  <Newsletter class="newsletter"></Newsletter>
</template>

<script>
import Newsletter from "@/components/Newsletter.vue";

export default {
 components: {
  Newsletter
 }
}
</script>

<!-- this is the change. Updated to have `::v-deep` to allow style to "leak" to the child component -->
<style scoped>
 ::v-deep .newsletter {
  background-color: green;
  text-align:left;
 }
</style>
```

See more at:

> https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Another option to consider is using global style in place of the local style and be sure that each shared class element has a unique parent.

In one component such as Subscribe:

```
<style lang="scss">
 .subscribe { 
  .newsletter {
   // style for this specific version of newsletter
  }
}
</style>
```

In another component where ".somethingelse" should be the specific type of component:

```
<style lang="scss">
 .somethingelse {
   .newsletter {
     // style for this other specific version of newsletter
   }
 }
</style>
```

More info about global specificity:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Thank you so much, '::v-deep' are exactly solution I was looking for.
Have a great day :)

Comment: @WatsadonramaiWiroonthunyatorn thanks for confirming! Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible! All you have to do is add the `scoped` [attribute to the style tag](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Element-selectors-with-scoped-use-with-caution).

Here is the snippet from the docs just for reference here:

```
<template>
  <button class="btn btn-close">X</button>
</template>

<style scoped>
.btn-close {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

This will only apply the styles locally, to the component which contains the style tag. Keep in mind though, you really should avoid using tag selectors because they are the most generic. It's a better practice to use a class selector because it has a higher specificity, meaning it is less likely to be over-written (id selectors or inline styles take precedence). I would suggest doing something like this:

```
<template>
 <h2>
  Subscribe to receive Newsletter
  </h2>
  <Newsletter class="newsletter"></Newsletter>
</template>

<script>
import Newsletter from "@/components/Newsletter.vue";

export default {
 components: {
  Newsletter
 }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
 .newsletter {
  background-color: green;
  text-align:left;
 }
</style>
```

In the example above, the `newsletter` class will make the background-color green *only* in this single-file component.

Comment: Thank, use attribute scope does work. but what if Newsletter component have more component like <h1> <h2><p> can I style each tag separately?

Comment: @WatsadonramaiWiroonthunyatorn Yes you can. Like I mentioned in my answer though, it's not a great CSS practice to use tag selectors. I would give each tag that you want to style a class using [BEM](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/) convention. This will help you to avoid over-writing styles and making your code more readable :)

Comment: Now I add a class "newsletter" to Newsletter component but I still can't style element inside like tag even if I add class like this `<label class="newsletter__label">Enter your email address here</label>` and `style .newsletter__label{color: yellow}`

Comment: Are you placing those style inside your `Newlsetter` component? Or inside a parent component?

Comment: in this case, I place style inside Subscribe.vue that I instance Newsletter not Newsletter.vue component itself

Comment: Did you try a selector like `.newsletter > label .newsletter__label`?

Comment: In that case try putting the style on the Newsletter component itself :)

Comment: @John Rice gave me the solution I want. Thanks for replying, 
Thank you for your time.  Have a great day :)